# How do I access the value of an array property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I access the value stored in the **description** property using javascript?

As seen in the image below (a screenshot from the browser console), the stored value is **[STK_CB - ] Request Cancelled by user**

[image: the strange JSON response]

In the browser console, I have tried `console.log(responseMan.payload["0"].jsonPayload.description);` which shows `undefined`. Where am I going wrong?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: it is JSON. use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `JSON.parse(responseMan.payload[0].jsonPayload).description` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `jsonPayload` is a string, not an object -- notice the double quotes around it. And the name of the property implies that it's JSON. You need to call `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object.

```
var payload = JSON.parse(responseMan.payload[0].jsonPayload);
console.log(payload.description);
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove " from index and do it like:

u also have to cast the json first

```
const jsonStr = responseMan.payload[0].jsonPayload;
const data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(data.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your json. Because you are trying to access responseMan.payload ["0"]. JsonPayload up there is a correct element in the json. But the description is a string value in responseMan.payload ["0"]. JsonPayload, therefore, must format the contents of responseMan.payload ["0"]. JsonPayload on a json object. Example var obj = JSON.parse (responseMan.payload ["0"]. JsonPayload); and so
description will be a json object

OR

You can fix that json in your backend and send that section as a json and not as a string

Comment: This data is most likely coming from a third party API - which means they'd have to fix it on their front end

Comment: Welcome to SO, Gilberto. It's good to use formatting, especially with code snippets and examples.